# WebAuthn with resident keys and no user validation in Chrome / Chromium

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, webauthn, yubikey

I'm trying to create a credential with resident key / discoverable credentials for username-less login:

```js
navigator.credentials.create({
  publicKey: {
    challenge: ...,
    timeout: ...,
    rp: { name: 'Some name' },
    user: { ... },
    pubKeyCredParams: [
      {"type":"public-key","alg":-7},
      {"type":"public-key","alg":-37},
      {"type":"public-key","alg":-257}]
    ],
    authenticatorSelection: {
      authenticatorAttachment: 'cross-platform',
      residentKey: 'required',
      requireResidentKey: true,
      userVerification: 'discouraged'
    }
  }
})
```

Unfortunately, Chrome still prompts the user to set a PIN or, if the hardware key does not support PINs, tells the user that the device is not supported. As if `userVerification: 'discouraged'` was just ignored by Chrome.

Our requirement is that that users can register and login without entering a username or PIN (with all the implied safety drawbacks).

Is there a way to achieve this with Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As if userVerification: 'discouraged' was just ignored by Chrome.

Discoverable credentials without user verification are not supported in Chrome. (Except for some platform authenticators which require that the device be unlocked but, correctly, don't report that as user verification.)

Setting an explicit `credProtect` level doesn't change that.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the state of things. This also seems to apply to Microsoft Edge with Chromium Engine. I guess it's just a security precaution.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using

```
CredProtect=userVerificationOptional
```

See
https://groups.google.com/a/fidoalliance.org/g/fido-dev/c/_GlMmEpHya8
And
https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/WebAuthn_Developer_Guide/Resident_Keys.html

edit: to be more precies, in your `create()` options, add:

```json
 extensions: {
  credentialProtectionPolicy: "userVerificationOptional"
},
```

and when calling `get()`, make sure you specify:

```json
  userVerification: "discouraged"
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly this didn't work.